# Select from a 2D list all rows where a column has a desired value

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy, multidimensional-array, transpose

I have a 2D list of MxN elements. I want to have all those rows where the column j has a certain value. My idea is to do:

```
my_2D_list = np.transpose(np.array(my_2D_list))
temp = my_2D_list[my_2D_list[j] == myvalue]
```

but temp is empty. If I print my_2D_list I can see the array is transposed, but it is like:

```
 [['0' '0' '0' ... '0' '0' '0']
  ['0' '0' '1' ... '75' '80' '80'] 
  ['60' '60' '0' ... '10' '108' '108']  ...
```

without the commas between columns, so I guess it is not splitting each row in columns in the new matrix, but is kind of a continuum... how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you to select the values from a column in a matrix you have to do it like this:

```
list[row_idx, col_idx]
```

where the first argument to the index is the row index, and the second argument is the column index. [You can check the docs in here.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html)

In your case, this would look like this: `my_2D_list[:, j]`. Here is a full example for you to check:

```
j = 2
n = 1

np.random.seed(42)
my_2D_list = np.random.randint(0, 3, 100).reshape((10, 10))

print(">>> Whole matrix\n%s" % my_2D_list)
print("\n>>> Column %d\n%s" % (j, my_2D_list[:,j]))
print("\n>>> Rows where column %d == %d \n%s" % (j, n, my_2D_list[my_2D_list[:,j] == n]))
```

Output:

```
>>> Whole matrix
[[2 0 2 2 0 0 2 1 2 2]
 [2 2 0 2 1 0 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 0 0 0 2 2 2]
 [1 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 0 2]
 [0 2 2 0 0 2 1 0 1 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 2 2 0 2 2]
 [1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]
 [2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1]
 [2 0 1 0 0 1 2 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0]]

>>> Column 2
[2 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 0]

>>> Rows where column 2 == 1 
[[0 0 1 1 0 0 0 2 2 2]
 [1 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 0 2]
 [1 0 1 0 1 2 2 0 2 2]
 [1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]
 [2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1]
 [2 0 1 0 0 1 2 0 1 0]]
```

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer since it's working and it was what I asked it, but actually, I found out that since one of my columns had text, although the column I was looking was an int and I was comparing to an int that index, I had to compare it to str(myvalue). Otherwise my approach would have also worked.